# Typecasting Point Value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm working on an assignment for my Intro to Java course and I'm currently stuck trying to sort an array of integers.

I get the values from a point object array, `p`, and pass them to an int array of the same size, `pSize`. All I need is the point object's value of `x` to be typecast to `int` and get the array sorted. However, that is not occuring. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class doCheckWin {
// Class Fields
private Point[] p;
private static int pSize;

/*
        Class Constructor.
        Creates an array of point objects that holds the user's
        location of pieces.
*/
public doCheckWin(Point[] p) {
        this.p = p;
        pSize = p.length;
}

public void checkHorizontal() {
        int[] col = new int[pSize];
        for(int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
            col[i] = (int)p[i].getX();
        }
        Arrays.sort(col);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(col));
    } 
}
```

Here's the method from another classthat passes the point object:

```
public void checkWin(Point[] p) {
    doCheckWin dcw = new doCheckWin(p);
    dcw.checkHorizontal();
}
```

When I print the array to screen, the values are ints...using `getX` changes them to double but when typecasting to `int` it's not working...

The problem is:

1. Typecasting the value of `x` (ie: 10.0) to an integer does not work. When printing the results out on the screen I still get 10.0.
2. `Arrays.sort(col)` is not sorting the array.

**Sample Output of What I'm Getting**

```
10.0
13.0
12.0
11.0
3.0
```

**What I Want**

```
3
10
11
12
13
```

Edit: Here's the code used to print out the array:

```
Arrays.sort(col);
for(int i=0; i<col.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(col[i]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are printing right array?

Comment: Are you printing col or p? Can you show the printing code?

Comment: Can you add the code you use to print out the array? Also there is no need to create a new Point object or cast - just do this: col[i] = p[i].x; The simplest option is usually the best one. :)

Comment: @RussHayward thanks for the pointer, hehe, I always tend to do things the most difficult way. I did typecast it and tried to sort it but still not luck, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the point of your Point object (no pun intended)?

What is the contents of p[]? Is it an array of Point objects like you said? If so, why are you creating a point object from a point object?

It looks like you want to do something like so:

```
int[] col = new int[pSize];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    col[i] = (int)p[i].getX();
}
Arrays.sort(col);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(col));
```

That seem to work for me.

Here is an example:

```
int pSize = 5;
Point[] p = new Point[pSize];

Random z = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i] = new Point(i+z.nextInt(5), i);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));

int[] col = new int[pSize];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    col[i] = (int)p[i].getX();
}
Arrays.sort(col);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(col));
```

Which gives:

```
[java.awt.Point[x=3,y=0], java.awt.Point[x=3,y=1], java.awt.Point[x=6,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=3,y=3], java.awt.Point[x=4,y=4]]
[3, 3, 6, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: thanks for your input. i've updated my OP with my whole class, maybe it will help. I've done something very similar to what you have above, but I'm still getting double values instead of ints and its not sorting...

Comment: Disregard that last comment, it all magically works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `Point` objects do absolutely nothing.
2. By sorting the integers stored in `col` you obviously do not sort any `Point` object or `p`, you know. All you modify are the contents of `col`, but they are *disconnected* from the other data.

Comment: I'm not trying to sort the point object, i'm trying to sort the integer array whose values I got after typecasting the point's x` values